# Programmatically choose item in select drop down

Tags: html

I have a  drop down:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

How would I select item 2 programmatically?

Comment: Are you talking about pre-selecting the item on page load, or selecting a form item on a remote web site, or ?

Comment: You'll need either client-, or server-, side scripting/programming. Which would you prefer?

Comment: Wow lots of different ways to do it. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First get a handle on that select somehow:

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[0];
```

Then manipulate the selectedIndex property (I believe it's a zero-based index):

```
select.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: Or did you want to select by value? That's a different answer.

Comment: How is browser compatibility with `selectedIndex`? Could not find any decent reference for that...

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about pre-selecting an item, simply set the item as "selected" as follows:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Surely just the presence of `selected` is sufficient, being a Boolean attribute? It doesn't, so far as I can remember, require a value.

Comment: @David Thomas: if you're using XHTML strict, you must say selected="selected". [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/Xhtml/xhtml_syntax.asp), among many others.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using plain HTML:

```
<option selected value="2">2</option>
```

If you're able to use jQuery, use the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val#val) method:

```
<select id="foo"> //give it an id

$("#foo").val("2");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select>   
     <option value="1">1</option>   
     <option value="2" selected>2</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery edition...

```
   $('#your_select').val('2');
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is this:

```
<select>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option selected value="2">2</option>
</select>
```