# Select option by code, which select is filled dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamically-generated, programmatically-created

I am trying to select programmatically an option from a HTML Select which is filled dynamically by code.

The selected is filled with a for:

```
for(var i =0; i< valores.length ; i++)
{
    var opcion= "<option value="+valores[i]['id_estado']+">"+valores[i]['nombre_estado']+"</option>";
    selectEstado.append(opcion);    
}
```

and then select a option with:

```
$("#select_estado option[value='"+valores[0]['estado']+"']").attr('selected', true);
```

but when I do the select locates in the value=0, any ideas?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206070/programmatically-choose-item-in-select-drop-down

Comment: Is my answer helped ?!

Comment: Thank you Francesco. I use that on my Javascript code, I put the select tag in the code because I know the value which has to be marked. Mehdi Bouzidi is a good answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how you did declare your `valores` array, so I felt free
>   to declare a new array that takes the `keys` you used in your
>   question.

So if you declared your `array` the same way I did then you shouldn't use this syntax `valores[i]['id_estado']` but you should use this one `valores[i].id_estado`

Otherwise, to select an `option` by it `value` you should use the simple function [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Finally I support my answer with this question: [Set select option 'selected', by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value)

```js
$(function(){

var valores={ 
0:{'id_estado':1,'nombre_estado':3},
1:{'id_estado':5,'nombre_estado':2},
2:{'id_estado':20,'nombre_estado':1}
        };
        
 var count=Object.keys(valores).length;
for(var i =count-1; i>= 0 ; i--)
{
    var opcion= "<option value="+valores[i].id_estado+">"+valores[i].nombre_estado+"</option>";
    $("#select_estado").append(opcion);      
}

$("button").on("click",function(){
$("select").val(valores[1].id_estado);
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select id="select_estado"></select>
 <button type="button" >Select</button>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate.

Comment: @HéctorCapulínPatiño welcome :) would you please click on approve the answer by clicking the **Check Mark**