# Programatically selecting an item from a <select> drop-down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a technical writer working to create a knowledgebase with Madcap Flare. I need my users to be able to select the version of the software that they are using so that I can serve the appropriate content.

I am using this guide: [Version Filtering with Madcap Flare](https://techwritersblog.com/madcap-flare-category/version-filters-madcap-flare/)

Flare allows me to tag content during the writing process, then I can use JS to target those tags to dynamically hide/show content based on the users selection from the  drop down by applying display="none" to all versions *not* selected. This all works but I am not able to have the most recent version preselected. On page load, all content is visible. If I use  the item will be select in the drop down, but it doesn't do anything in terms of applying display="none" to all other versioned content. Any ideas?

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" > /*<![CDATA[*/ function getElementsWithAttribute(attr) {
  var elementsWithAttribute = [];
  var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].getAttribute(attr)) {
      elementsWithAttribute.push(elements[i]);
    }
  }
  return elementsWithAttribute;
}

function showHideVersion() {
  var elements = getElementsWithAttribute('data-mc-conditions');
  var e = document.getElementById('version-select');
  var selectedVersion = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].getAttribute('data-mc-conditions').indexOf(selectedVersion) > -1) {
      elements[i].classList.remove("hidden1");
      localStorage.id = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    } else {
      elements[i].classList.add("hidden1");
    }
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var elements = getElementsWithAttribute('data-mc-conditions');
  var locals = localStorage.getItem('id');
  if (locals == null) {
    localStorage.id = "Default.V9";
    locals = localStorage.getItem('id');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (elements[i].getAttribute('data-mc-conditions').indexOf(locals) > -1) {
        elements[i].classList.remove("hidden1");
        document.getElementById('version-select').value = locals;
      } else {
        elements[i].classList.add("hidden1");
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (elements[i].getAttribute('data-mc-conditions').indexOf(locals) > -1) {
        elements[i].classList.remove("hidden1");
        document.getElementById('version-select').value = locals;
      } else {
        elements[i].classList.add("hidden1");
      }
    }
  }
} /*]]>*/ < /script>
```

```html
<div class="version-select">
  <select id="version-select" onchange="showHideVersion()" width="100%">
    <option value="Default.V8">Version 8</option>
    <option value="Default.V9">Version 9</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically choose item in select drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206070/programmatically-choose-item-in-select-drop-down)